# How to get the IIS field names inside logExtFileFlags attribute in applicationHost file?

Tags: c#, iis

just trying to obtain the IIS logging field names from the logExtFileFlags attribute inside the applicationHost.config file but all I get is a number which I believe are IIS flags. Here is my code:

```
        using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
            ConfigurationSection sitesSection = config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites");
            ConfigurationElementCollection sitesCollection = sitesSection.GetCollection();

            ConfigurationElement siteElement = FindElement(sitesCollection, "site", "name", @"Default Web Site");
            if (siteElement == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Element not found!");
            ConfigurationElement logFileElement = siteElement.GetChildElement("logFile");
            var test = logFileElement["logExtFileFlags"];   //test = 3276799 this represents flags
            //<logFile logExtFileFlags="Date, Time, ClientIP, UserName, SiteName, ComputerName, BytesSent, BytesRecv, TimeTaken" period="Hourly" enabled="true" />
        }
```

A little update...it looks like I found all the values for each constant and now it is a matter to find a function to read the number 3276799, check each constant value and return the field names:

```
        const int LogExtFileDate = 1;
        const int LogExtFileTime = 2;
        const int LogExtFileClientIp = 4;...
```

Thank you
Max

Comment: Check Jexus Manager source code, https://GitHub.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager

Comment: I looked through the code (huge) and the only thing I found was the method SelectFields() at the LoggingFeature.cs class. I think what I need now is just a generic function with logic to be able to read the number 3276799 and go through all the constants to figure out which ones have the flag on. That number is the sum up of all constants that have the field turned on. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/master/JexusManager.Features.Logging/FieldsDialog.cs you can get flags via `Enum.GetValues` and then using bit wise operations.

Comment: I see I can extract some code from that example thanks. I chose to go an easier route by using the appcmd.exe from IIS to extract all the info I needed. Thanks again.